# Factor analysis and multiple regression

Tags: multiple-regression, factor-analysis

I have a question about how to do a multiple regression after having the result of the factor analysis.

I have the data from a questionnaire and the result of the factor analysis indicate that I have 4 factor solution.

My question is what to do after doing the factor analysis ??
How can I find the relation between those 4 factors and the dependent variable ??

Comment: Did you do factor analysis after removing dependent variable from data or with it?

Comment: Yes I did the analysis only for the 4 factors.. without the dependent variable.

Comment: Your should also mention how many predictor variables did you subject to factor analysis? Also, regarding what to do further, see answer by @PeterFlom

Answer (score 1):

You can use the factor scores as independent variables in a regression, just as you would use any other independent variables.